# SASS: Overriding bootstrap scss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

This is my `styles.scss` file content:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.scss";
@import "mixins.scss";
// Global CSS
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import "global.scss";
@import "nav.scss";
@import "resume-item.scss";
@import "bootstrap-overrides.scss";
```

Using this inport order, font is loaded correctly:
[image]

However, if I write `@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';` after `@import "global.scss";` font is not loaded:

[image]

I don't quite figure out why it's not applied.

`_global.scss` file is:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  @include heading-font;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: $gray-800;
}
```

and `heading-font` is a mixin declared on `_mixins.scss`:

```
@mixin heading-font {
  font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', serif;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Load your custom SASS **after** Bootstrap. Bootstrap using the heading tags in its own CSS.

Comment: I don't quite figure out what you mean... is there any rule should I follow? put my custom files before bootstrap i.e.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *bootstrap.scss* includes it's own *_type.scss* file, which in exchange contains this style at the very beginning:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
.h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
    margin-bottom: $headings-margin-bottom;
    font-family: $headings-font-family;
    font-weight: $headings-font-weight;
    line-height: $headings-line-height;
    color: $headings-color;
}
```

So your styles are simply overwritten because of the order of the *scss* includes.